# Hide 'Pagination' panel if a condition has met

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, dom, vuetify.js

I'm trying to hide the pagination panel if the amount of items is less than 5. So no witchcraft and it should actually be very easy with DOM manipulation. But however, my if statement is not working and I don't know why.

The project is based on vue.js, vuetify and with ts.

I added this code snippet with the objective, that when a condition has met, the vuetify class 'd-none' will be added or removed from the v-row:

```
hidePagination() {
    const paginationEl = document.querySelector('.pagination--custom');
    const itemsValue = this.totalItems;

    if (itemsValue > 5) {
      paginationEl.classList.remove('d-none');
      // console.log('fn has fired and removed the d-none cl');
    }
    return paginationEl.classList.add('d-none');
    // console.log('fn has fired and added the the d-none cl');
  }
```

the whole code of the component is here:

```
<template>
  <v-row class="pagination--custom">
    <v-col class="pagination__controls-container pagination__select-container">
      <eg-select
        v-if="itemsPerPageOptions.length > 1"
        :items="itemsPerPageOptions"
        :value="itemsPerPage"
        filled
        label=""
        dense
        class="pagination__select"
        @input="onItemsPerPageChange($event)"
      ></eg-select>
      <label class="pagination__label mt-3">
        Showing {{ startItem }} - {{ endItem }} of
        {{ totalItems }}
      </label>
    </v-col>
    <v-col
      class="pagination__controls-container pagination__buttons-container text-right px--sm-auto"
    >
      <v-pagination
        :total-visible="totalVisiblePageitems"
        :value="value"
        :length="length"
        @input="onPageChange($event)"
      ></v-pagination>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import EgSelect from '@/common/components/forms/select.vue';

@Component({
  name: 'EgPagination',
  components: {
    EgSelect,
  },
})
export default class Pagination extends Vue {
  @Prop({ required: true }) value: number;

  @Prop({ required: true }) itemsPerPage: number;

  @Prop({ default: () => [25, 50, 100, 500] }) itemsPerPageOptions: number[];

  @Prop({ required: true })
  totalItems: number;

  hidePagination() {
    const paginationEl = document.querySelector('.pagination--custom');
    const itemsValue = this.totalItems;

    if (itemsValue > 5) {
      paginationEl.classList.remove('d-none');
      // console.log('fn has fired and removed the d-none cl');
    }
    return paginationEl.classList.add('d-none');
    // console.log('fn has fired and added the the d-none cl');
  }

  onPageChange(page: number) {
    /**
     * Called when changing page
     * @property {number} page
     */
    this.$emit('input', page);
  }

  onItemsPerPageChange(amount: number) {
    this.$emit('update:items-per-page', amount);
    if (this.value > 1) {
      this.$emit('input', 1);
    }
  }

  get totalVisiblePageitems() {
    if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.xs) {
      return 3;
    }
    if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown) {
      return 5;
    }
    if (this.$vuetify.breakpoint.md || this.$vuetify.breakpoint.lg) {
      return 6;
    }
    return 10;
  }

  get startItem() {
    if (this.value === 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return (this.value - 1) * this.itemsPerPage + 1;
  }

  get endItem() {
    const endItem = this.value * this.itemsPerPage;
    if (endItem > this.totalItems) {
      return this.totalItems;
    }
    return endItem;
  }

  get length() {
    return Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage);
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .pagination__select {
    display: none;
  }
  .pagination__label {
    display: none;
  }
}
.pagination--custom {
  margin-top: 16px;
  .pagination__controls-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    &.pagination__select-container {
      justify-content: flex-start;
      .pagination__select {
        min-width: 64px;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 115px;
        height: 56px;
        margin-right: 8px;
        .v-input__slot {
          min-height: 56px !important;
          border-radius: 4px;

          &:before {
            border: none;
          }
        }
        .v-text-field__details {
          min-height: 0px;
          padding: 0px;
          display: none;

          .v-messages {
            min-height: 0px;
          }
        }
      }
      .pagination__label {
        color: var(--v-lightgray-darken4);
      }
    }
    &.pagination__buttons-container {
      justify-content: flex-end;
      .v-pagination {
        .v-pagination__navigation,
        .v-pagination__item {
          background: var(--v-lightgray-base);
          color: var(--v-primary-base);
          min-width: 56px;
          min-height: 56px;
          margin: 0 4px;
          box-shadow: none;
          border-radius: 0px;
        }
        .v-pagination__item--active.primary {
          background-color: var(--v-primary-base) !important;
          border-color: var(--v-primary-base) !important;
          color: white !important;

          .v-icon {
            color: white !important;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

What is wrong with my approach?
Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue I think is your function always adds the class **d-none** to your pagination element, regardless the number of items is greater than 5 or not.

You can modify your function like this:

```
hidePagination() {
  const paginationEl = document.querySelector('.pagination--custom');
  const itemsValue = this.totalItems;

  if (itemsValue > 5) {
    paginationEl.classList.remove('d-none');
  } else {
    paginationEl.classList.add('d-none');
  }
}
```

Hope This Will Help...